# Eclipse: detach package explorer, outline panels?

Tags: eclipse

I'm in a constant battle with Eclipse to free up more screen real estate for code instead of decoration. I can maximize the code window by double clicking on it, getting rid of the  package explorer, outline, and other panels, but I do use the other panels on occasion, particularly the package explorer for SVN integration.

Is there a way to detach the various panels and have them pop up based on hotkeys? I'm imagining having the code window maximized all the time, with a hotkey to bring forward the package explorer as a separate pop-up window when needed, with the pop-up going into the background as a normal window when I click on the code window to go back to editing.

Answer (score 2):

This is the closest I could come to what you want:

Under Window->Preferences->General->Perspectives, change the second setting "Open a new view" to "As a fast view".  Then, close Package Explorer view.  The next time it comes up, it (and any other newly opened view) will be a fast view: it'll disappear when it loses focus.

As another answerer mentioned, the PE has a keyboard shortcut.  I find its default a little unfriendly so I'd recommend changing it under Window->Preferences->General->Keys.  The Package Explorer command is under "Show View (View: Package Explorer)". Ctrl+Shift+P seems like a good option.  Then, you can just hit Ctrl+Shift+P, do something in PE, click back in the code window, and watch PE disappear.  Note: My new keyboard shortcut stopped working sporadically if I changed the "As a fast view" setting first.  Re-entering the keyboard shortcut seemed to fix this.

You can change a fast view to the normal type of view by repositioning it via dragging.

Answer (score 1):

Minimize the package explorer, then use: `Alt-Shift-Q then P`.

This will "Show View (Package Explorer)" as a fast view.

As discovered using `Shift-Ctl-L` to show keyboard short cuts.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I just code on the J2EE Perspective with all stuff gone. When I want to do something else I change to other perspective

Answer (score 0):

You could access it via Ctrl-3 (as pretty much anything else in Eclipse), and close it with escape. When you hit Ctrl-3 again, it will be the top choice.

Answer (score 0):

Activate Package explorer by hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> then <kbd>P</kbd>. Minimize it as fast view by clicking the minus button [image]on Package Explorer(You can assign short cut key to `Minimizes the active view or editor` command in `Windows > Preferences > Keys` section).
Maximize the editor by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>. You can activate again package explorer as said above. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> to active editor after using package explorer.

All these can be done with hot keys NO MOUSE CLICKS.